# How do I use shinjs::extendShinyjs() in a shiny module?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

`shinyjs::extendShinyjs()` does not seem to work in a Shiny module without at least some namespacing.

Here is an example of using a simple JS extension to increase an input value (which works as intended):

```
library(shiny)

ui <-  tagList(
  fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.increase_click_count = function(val){
        Shiny.setInputValue('count', +val + 1, { priority: 'event' })
      }", functions = "increase_click_count"
    ),
    actionButton("increase","Increase"),
    numericInput("count", "Count", 0),
    textOutput("clicks")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$increase, {
    shinyjs::js$increase_click_count(input$count)
  })

  output$clicks = renderText(input$count)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, when I wrap this logic in a module, the `shinyjs.increase_click_count()` function no longer updates the value:

```
library(shiny)

module_ui <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = paste0("shinyjs.increase_click_count = function(val){
        Shiny.setInputValue('", NS(id, "count"), "', +val + 1, { priority: 'event' })
      }"), functions = "increase_click_count"
    ),
    actionButton("increase","Increase"),
    numericInput(NS(id, "count"), "Count", 0),
    textOutput(NS(id,"clicks"))
  )
}

module_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$increase, {
      shinyjs::js$increase_click_count(input$count)
    })
    
    output$clicks = renderText(input$count)
  })
}

ui <-  fluidPage(
  module_ui("mod")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  module_server("mod")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How do I properly deal with Shiny module namespaces in Javascript?

Comment: Try `actionButton(ns("increase"),"Increase"),`, where `ns <- NS(id)` is defined just above `tagList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a a NS call

```
library(shiny)

module_ui <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = paste0("shinyjs.increase_click_count = function(val){
        Shiny.setInputValue('", NS(id, "count"), "', +val + 1, { priority: 'event' })
      }"), functions = "increase_click_count"
    ),
    actionButton(NS(id, "increase"), "Increase"),
    numericInput(NS(id, "count"), "Count", 0),
    textOutput(NS(id,"clicks"))
  )
}

module_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$increase, {
      shinyjs::js$increase_click_count(input$count)
    })
    
    output$clicks = renderText(input$count)
  })
}

ui <-  fluidPage(
  module_ui("mod")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  module_server("mod")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Part of my issue in my actual app was that `shinyjs::extendShinyjs()` did not register unless it was within a `tagList()` within the module. I am unable to reproduce fully with this example, but that seems to be another good troubleshooting step.